# Why do (some) C questions get 'Run code snippet'?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-snippets

The question [Adding perfect squares to get input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331706/adding-perfect-squares-to-get-input) isn't a particularly good question, but it does show the 'Run code snippet' button:

[image: Showing C code and 'Run code snippet' button for SO 26331706]

However, pressing the button doesn't do anything very useful except format the code on one line since there isn't any HTML lurking around.

Why is the system offering to run a C program when it doesn't know how to compile and run C programs?

---

**Answer:** it seems to be user confusion (error, except that the error arises because the user doesn't understand what the snippets system is for).

For the question referenced, I've removed the snippet-related markup.

Comment: I've seen quite a few of these over the past few days - it's a pain having to keep editing them out.

Comment: A question that contains an edit **Answer: ..** ... Meta *does* work different!

Comment: I've [run into one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604227/this-simple-c-program-running-in-the-input-string-can-not-may-be-strcmp-function) today. Maybe the "code snippet" UI should be renamed to something more explicit so it's obvious that C code samples are not "snippets". I suspect the average user is not aware of the difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because people click the wrong button - they create a stack snippet rather than a regular code block.  It prompts for stuff in javascript, but people can put anything in there if they want.

```js
I mean there is nothing stopping me from typing regular text as a stack snippet; people might put their code wherever they want.
```

In these cases I usually edit the post to remove the snippet, as it doesn't make sense to have it like that.

Comment: OK; I see.  I've not bothered to look hard at snippets because it doesn't support the languages I know well enough to answer questions about.  Yes, it is easy enough to remove the markup for snippets.  I'm left wondering if the system should be able to spot that there's a problem for itself (like 'no tags in the HTML code')?

Comment: Yes, the system should spot this.