# Motivation for policy to allow stack-snippets on any block, even irrelevant ones?

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

I'm used to removing the "run code snippet" on occasion. But I'm looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30155406/608639), and I'm shaking my head in disbelief at the misuse.

[This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274338/608639) suggests that it's user confusion, and it's easy to blame the user. While I have been able to located related posts, I cannot find a definitive post on why the feature can be applied to any block. That is, I'm interested in the thinking behind the Stack Overflow policy of *"let them apply it to everything, even nonsensical things"*. At some point in time, the site made that policy decision.

Why is "run code snippet" allowed on irrelevant code and other irrelevant blocks like Android logcat output? Why did the site think that was a good policy?

Comment: **For the same reason, most likely, as it is 'allowed' to bold entire paragraphs and even make them Header 1. That is, the SO editor does not *know* what the user applies his markup on.**

Comment: @Jongware - thanks for your speculation on the matter. But lets keep it on-topic.

Comment: @jww how is that not on-topic? You ask why it's *"allowed"*; the alternative is some means of defining what it should be applied to and enforcing that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - it does not address the thrust of the question, which is the site's policy decision. Also, its pure speculation on the implementation detail. And its faulty: tags on the question should filter the egregious offenders, so the claim is frivolous.

Comment: @jww I'm not sure there **is** a *"policy decision"*, as such. The functionality was provided for a purpose (see e.g. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ which also explains that it's just a fancy interface for a specially-formatted set of code blocks); if people misuse it then we try to educate them. Are you suggesting that the snippets should only work on questions tagged CSS, HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: And similar: code ticks only to bona fide in line code, `#` only to phrases that can reasonably be headers, and italics only to words that SO deems safely to emphasize. My speculation stands: the SO editor is not smart enough to recognize to what a user applies certain markup; and neither should it try to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I'm not sure removing the last paragraph is a good idea. It opens the question up to [unrelated opinions on the matter](http://bikeshed.com/), which I am ***not*** interested in. Reading comprehension is a big problem on SO and MSO. Related: [Why is reading comprehension skills so low on SO and MSO?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293917/608639)

Comment: @Jongware - perhaps you should keep it on-topic by discussing the site's policy decision, and stop [bike shedding](http://bikeshed.com/) about why you think its allowed. I clearly stated I was not interested in personal opinions on the matter.

Comment: @jww no, it doesn't. If there *are* irrelevant responses, point them out or flag them. Throwing around accusations of bike shedding *before you've had a single response* is a waste of everyone's time. I'd be inclined to focus on the writing, rather than the reading; if your questions are being misinterpreted, *make them clearer*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - *"Throwing around accusations of bike shedding before you've had a single response..."* - that draws from my years of experience on SO and MSO. The community ***is*** that predictable. Case in point: look at the first comment.

Comment: @jww as I've already mentioned, I disagree that the comment is off-topic; it's a perfectly reasonable supposition, directly related to the topic at hand, and likely as close as you'll get to an answer. If you find the community so objectionable, *stop participating*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - *...stop participating..."* - yes, that's the best defense; and the one that I have adopted. But on occasion, I have to come here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - *"I disagree that the comment is off-topic..."* - that's like asking a drunk if he is drunk. What answer did you expect... You're one of the offenders (as am I by engaging in this unrelated banter).

Comment: @jonrsharpe - *"...directly related to the topic at hand..."* - its not directly related. The topic at hand is the site's policy decision; not speculation on what is easy or hard. Like I said: [Why is reading comprehension skills so low on SO and MSO?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293917/608639). I even spelled it out for the comprehension-challenged, but some anti-genius editor removed it from the question.

Comment: If you want to discuss a policy decision, please cite the decision. I don't see anything to discuss here otherwise.

Comment: You're trying to *locate* a policy decision? That's not what your question says. What makes you think there is one? And perhaps, instead of linking to your passive-aggressive question/rant about reading comprehension for the 4th time, you should contemplate the quality of your *writing*.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - *"... you should contemplate the quality of your writing"* - fair enough, good point. What do you suggest to make it clearer?

Comment: I can't say, because I still don't really understand what you want. I think you're looking for an official statement on whether posting non-executable snippets is "allowed"? If so, you could clarify what you mean by "allowed". You're not asking why it's not automatically disallowed, I think..

Comment: @Blorgbeard - *"you're looking for an official statement on whether posting non-executable snippets is "allowed"* - not exactly. I know its allowed (*q.v.*). I'm trying to understand why the site thought it was a good policy to allow it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no policy. It was just a new feature, and the way the feature works is just adding additional syntax that can be used with the existing Markdown in order to make it work. Very often when features get implemented, there's something that gets overlooked or that can be done better. That doesn't mean we created a *policy* about doing it that way, it means we *didn't think about it*.

So if you see something that can be improved, **write up a feature request to have it changed**. Questioning a nonexistent policy is not going to get us anywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much. *"Questioning a nonexistent policy is not going to get us anywhere..."* - we don't know that until we ask. *q.v.*

Comment: Now related: [Please restrict the use of stack-snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293920).