# Please restrict the use of stack-snippets

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

The question that triggered this request is [Android - get data detail listview using asynctask in fragment and service using codeigneter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30155406/608639). In the question, stack-snippets were applied to nearly everything, including Android logcat.

According to [Motivation for policy to allow stack-snippets on any block, even irrelevant ones?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293919/608639), allowing the stack-snippet to be applied to all blocks was an oversight.

It appears the use of stack-snippets is incorrect among some of the new site users. Its a disservice to the community and user since the user is not learning to use the site correctly. And its a disservice to the user because of the propensity to negatively receive the question.

**Request**: please restrict the use of stack-snippets to relevant blocks. Or at least prohibit them from irrelevant blocks.

The request above offers two different strategies. The first, *restrict the use of stack-snippets to relevant blocks*, may be a hard problem. The second, *prohibit them from irrelevant blocks*, is likely an easier problem.

For the second strategy, its *seems* easy enough to prohibit stack-snippets on question that lack the related technology tags, like [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html); or prohibit them if they lack an inline language comments/syntax highlighting comments like `<!-- language: lang-html -->`.

Another strategy is to have an interpreter try to run the stack-snippet or symbolically execute the stack-snippet. If its not able to execute it, then it should be kicked back to the user for improvement (or moved to the Low Quality queue for potential improvement).

---

I'm not sure if this should be tagged with [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug). According to Animuson's comment at the related question, its an oversight and should probably be a bug.

In either case, [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) creates an actionable item for the site to act upon. Whether its acted upon is a different story.

Related to acting upon appropriately tagged questions, see [What is the purpose of having tags if they are not honored?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256116).

---

Also related:

- [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)
- [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/173448)

Comment: @Jeroen - that would be really sad. If it is a duplicate, then it means the problem was identified and reported; but nothing was been done. Luckily, it was just reported with a suggestion to add a tool-tip; and not implement proactive measures like restricting based on tags.

Comment: Matthew 15:2 "And thus God came down from the heavens and bestowed upon us the gift of bounties to kick SO employees into place".

Comment: @Jeroen - Meta Stack Overflow does not have bounties.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel, Makoto, Hans Passant, John Conde, Have No Display Name - You killed the bug report off, which created an actionable item. There's only discussions and feature request remaining, which are ***not*** actionable items. We are still getting misuse of stack snippets: [Openssl Server wrong cipher suite or no connection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30446431/608639). What are you going to do to fix the problem? Please don't stop the meddling - please follow it through all the way until the problem is resolved.

Comment: At 18.5k rep, you know you can just edit the stack snippet out, right?

Comment: @nhgrif  - perhaps. But its not clear to me that's the correct course. The promotion from Discussion to Bug is drastic, and it changes the dynamics of the post. If you claim that's the correct course, then maybe you should take that action. As always, thanks for the [opinion](http://bikeshed.com/). That's one thing we can always count on here!

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel, Makoto, Hans Passant, John Conde, Have No Display Name -  We are still seeing this issue on the site. See, for example, [Old-style-SSL with library gloox?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30673635) What have you done other than to close the one bug report that creates an actionable item?

Comment: If it bothers you, write up an answer with your proposed solution on the duplicate instead.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. Its not clear to me a duplicate should be promoted to a bug report. But thanks for telling me what I should do. And thanks for your opinion. Perhaps you should continue meddling and see this through until the issue is fixed.

Comment: Jeroen Vannevel, Makoto, Hans Passant, John Conde, Have No Display Name -  We still seem to be having problems with this: [Add More Button not Working - ScoreBook.java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30699652/608639). Please continue until the problem is fixed. I'm beggining to think closing the bug report was a bad idea. Perhpas you should not meddle in the future.